# How to make a class have a field for an object made in another class

Tags: java

I have a class called `NumFiles` which is made up of arrays of matrices:

```
public class NumFiles {

    private int[][] one = makeMatrix("one.txt");
    private int[][] two= makeMatrix("two.txt");
    private int[][] three= makeMatrix("three.txt");
    private int[][] four= makeMatrix("four.txt");
    private int[][] five= makeMatrix("five.txt");
    private int[][] six= makeMatrix("six.txt");
    private int[][] seven= makeMatrix("seven.txt");
    private int[][] eight= makeMatrix("eight.txt");
    private int[][] nine= makeMatrix("nine.txt");
    private int[][] zero= makeMatrix("zero.txt");

    public NumFiles() {
    }
    ...
}
```

I then made another class called `ImgClass` which needs to have a field for the `NumFiles` object. In `ImgClass` the `NumFiles` object needs to be accessed in order to use the matrices it's made up of.

My question is, how do I call the `NumFiles` object in my `ImgClass` class? How can I make a field of a `NumFiles` object in another class?

Comment: `Numfiles file = new Numfiles()`?

Comment: you literally declare the field and initialize it :D

Comment: @KevinEsche I did that and I get an error saying "NumFiles cannot be resolved to a type" and to create a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it in the constructor or in a setter, or instantiate the field:

```
public class ImgClass {
    private NumFiles numFiles; // choice 2,3,4
    // private NumFiles numFiles = new NumFiles(); // choice 1

    public ImgClass(NumFiles numFiles) { //choice 2
        this.numFiles = numFiles;
    }

    public ImgClass() { //choice 3
        this.NumFiles = new NumFiles();       
    }

    //public ImgClass() { //choice 1 or 4
    //}

    public void setNumFiles(NumFiles numFiles) { //choice 4
        this.numFiles = numFiles;
    }
}
```

For choice 1:

```
ImgClass imgClass = new ImgClass();
```

For choice 2:

```
ImgClass imgClass = new ImgClass(new NumFiles());
```

For choice 3:

```
ImgClass imgClass = new ImgClass();
```

For choice 4:

```
ImgClass imgClass = new ImgClass();
imgClass.setNumFiles(new NumFiles())
```

Comment: I try any of these and it says "NumFiles cannot be resolved to a type" and I should create a class called NumFiles.

Comment: You said _I have a class called NumFiles_ . Probably an import statement in `ImgClass` is enough `import your.package.path.NumFiles`, where `package your.package.path` is the top most row in your `NumFiles` class